# Can you read video files off a HyperDeck Studio Pro 2?

Tags: video, ssd

Is there a way to connect a Hyperdeck Studio Pro 2 directly to a computer, and edit the video files directly? It has a Thunderbolt connection, but it says that it's for "capture of video and audio" which sounds like you would be capturing to a file on the computer, rather than reading the previously captured file on the SSD.

https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/hyperdeckstudio/techspecs/W-HYD-03

Currently our process involves removing the two SSD's from Hyperdeck, and putting them into an SSD Dock.

That introduces several adverse variables into the workflow:

1. The video capture person may forget to remove them and dock them at the computer. This matters because the editing person works remotely, and logs into the editing computer.
2. The dock connections are fiddly, and I can see over time that the SSD's SATA connectors will be stressed and become a point of failure.
3. It seems unnecessary.  It would be better to just read the files directly off the deck so that the drives can stay where they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [HyperDeck manual mentions](http://documents.blackmagicdesign.com/HyperDeck/HyperDeck_Manual_2015-01-19.pdf) :

> Accessing Your Clips
> To access your clips, simply connect the SSD to
> your computer using an SSD dock. You can either drag the files from
> the SSD directly to a local hard drive, or you can work directly from
> the SSD.

There's no mention of reading the clips via the Thunderbolt interface.

Comment: All the documentation I could find seems to agree with that.  I don't understand why they couldn't have included this as a feature.

Interestingly, you CAN stream the video on the SSD's through the thunderbolt cable if you want to capture the video on your computer.  I'm not sure why that would be beneficial in terms of workflow.